# TypeError: display() missing 1 required positional argument: 'd'

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning

I'm trying kaggle million song recommender system and i'm trying to use these codes to test.

```
from Tools.scripts.dutree import display

track_metadata_df = pd.read_csv('../input/song_data.csv')
count_play_df = pd.read_csv('../input/10000.txt', sep='\t', header=None, names= 
['user','song','play_count'])
print('First see of track metadata:')
print('Number of rows:', track_metadata_df.shape[0])
print('Number of unique songs:', len(track_metadata_df.song_id.unique()))
display(track_metadata_df.head())
print('Note the problem with repeated track metadata. Let\'s see of counts play song by users:')
```

I use display to show the result but it shows me error

```
TypeError: display() missing 1 required positional argument: 'd'
```

But when i try with print , it shows the result .

PS I'm very new in ML field and any advice are welcome.

Comment: Paste the full error, not just last line

Comment: here is the full line line 39, in <module>
    display(track_metadata_df.head())
TypeError: display() missing 1 required positional argument: 'd'

Comment: Check this: [Python code coverage for Tools/scripts/dutree.py](http://coverage.livinglogic.de/Tools/scripts/dutree.py.html). You need one more variable d in the input.

Comment: thank you very much. i got the answer

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)